# How can i test the doFilter method?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, springmockito

I try to test this method:

```
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response,
    final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    final HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    final HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    if (httpRequest.getSession(true).getAttribute("connected") == null) {
        httpResponse.sendRedirect(request.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/");
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Here my test:

```
@Test
public void testDoFilter() throws IOException, ServletException {

    MockServletContext servletContext = new MockServletContext();
    MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest(servletContext);
    MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
    MockHttpSession session = new MockHttpSession();
    FilterChain chain = Mockito.mock(FilterChain.class);
    String url = "/private/";
    request.setContextPath("/private/");

    UserFilter userfilter = new UserFilter();
    userfilter.doFilter(request, response, chain);
    Mockito.verify(chain, Mockito.times(0)).doFilter(request, response);
    request.setSession(session);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("connected", "toto");
    Mockito.verify(chain, Mockito.times(1)).doFilter(request, response);
}
```

but the last Mockito.verify don't run. I don't also understand when I do

```
request.getAttribute("connected")
```

I obtain `"toto"` but `null` when I do

```
request.getSession(true).getAttribute("connected").
```

Can you explain and help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The last `Mockito.verify(chain, Mockito.times(1)).doFilter(request, response);` fails because, request's session contains the key/value **"connected"**, so `doFilter` didn't called.

What about `request.getAttribute("connected")` vs `request.getSession(true).getAttribute("connected")`, I got `null` for the first, and `toto` for the second.